# C# changing object from other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm creating an agenda which can be used by voice.
Furthermore there's a virtual assistant(VA) who gives feedback and has some AI to get and keep a nice daily rhythm.

The situation is that I have a public static List agenda.

Agenda is an abstract class which currently has 9 different Agenda types.
this is the data core of the programm. This contains everything the programm needs to know.

The main thread contains the GUI and the usability people might expect with an agenda.

Everything the virtual assistant needs to do is bing done in a different thread. This is mainly checking the agenda and ask some questions if people want to do anything in the agenda.

The tricky part is when I also want to add things to the agenda from certain logics (adding AI so to speak), like daily meals. This comes from the VA thread but I cannot change Agenda.agenda from there and get an error, saying that the collection was modified.

I've tried locking it, but there's no difference.

adding meals to today:

```
    public void Meal()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime morning = date;
        morning = morning.ChangeTime(8, 0, 0, 0);

        DateTime afternoon = date;
        afternoon = afternoon.ChangeTime(12, 0, 0, 0);

        DateTime evening = date;
        evening = evening.ChangeTime(16, 30, 0, 0);

        if (!meal && date.Hour < 21)
        {
            if(date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
                toAdd.Add(new Task("broodbuffet", morning, new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>()));
            else
                toAdd.Add(new Task("ontbijt", morning, new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>()));
            toAdd.Add(new Task("lunch", afternoon, new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>()));
            toAdd.Add(new Task("diner", evening, new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>()));

            meal = true;
        }

        if (date.Hour > 22)
            meal = false;
    }
```

in the class where I do the basics with my VA:

```
ai.Meal();
UpdateAgenda();
```

method to update in thread:

```
private void UpdateAgenda()
    {
        if (ai.GetToAdd().Count != 0)
        {
            Agenda.agenda.AddRange(ai.GetToAdd());
        }
    }
```

and with lock:

```
private void UpdateAgenda()
    {
        if (ai.GetToAdd().Count != 0)
        {
            lock (Agenda.agenda)
            {
                Agenda.agenda.AddRange(ai.GetToAdd());
            }
        }
    }
```

So in short, how to add Agenda items to my agenda from the VA thread?

Comment: What does `ai.GetToAdd()` do? I am presuming it also iterates through `Agenga.agenda` while items are being added. But it's still not entirely clear what's going on in this code. Why did you post the `Meal` method? Does it have anything to do with your problem?

Comment: Is your reading code in the thread that isn't adding, using a `foreach`? On which thread is the exception raised?

Comment: Also, a couple of notes: 1. I would advise using more meaningful names (for example, if `toAdd` was named `tasks`, it would be much clearer that it contains a list of tasks). 2. Singletons are evil, avoid them. 3. Locking over a public object instance is a bad practice, avoid it. Agenda should do all the locking internally, if it needs to be synchronized. 4. If you are using multiple threads, you should avoid using unnecessary fields for storing data. It would be much better if `Meal` would return a new list and you would simply write `AddToAgenda(Meal());`.

Comment: I dont code multithread applications much but just brainstorming.wont it work if you make a listener class in the gui thread . The other two threads can change the properties of the listener class when needed. Both classes will check the listener class in some interval.(check every 500 miliseconds for example)

Comment: to answer the questions here: toAdd is a List filled with agenda items which needs to be added to Agenda.agenda. and the GetToAdd method is just a getter for this list. Meal method was just added to show the process. The suggestion mentioned below to lock the foreach loop that checks Agenda.agenda is probably the solution, but got to test that. Which I don't have time for today. And I know locking a public static object is a bad idea, but have to try something.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the locking, but you can't only lock when you change the property.

The lock doesn't lock the property, it locks the code, so you have to have a lock around *all* code that uses the property, so that the code that changes the property can lock out the code that reads from the property.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to the error you got ("Collection changed"), maybe you iterate over any collection in the Agenda object with a foreach loop? When a collection changes within a foreach loop (in your case, by a another thread), the IEnumerator.MoveNext throws exactly such error.
If this is the problem, you need to lock the whole foreach loop.